# Logical or / and in regex comparisons

Tags: kdb

In kdb can i do something like:

```
"hello" like "[hello|goodbye]"
1b
```

?

I can do:

```
any "hello" like/: ("hello";"goodbye")
1b
```

However, it isn't really in the spirit of what I was hoping for.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to avoid a long cascading (x like y0) |( x like y1) | (x like y2) .... style comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'like' has a limited regex capabilities mostly targeting the use cases of finacial domain data patterns.
Regex supported by 'like' is documented here: https://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/regex/

Depending on your requirement, you could also use other KDB operators. For  example, if its an exact match your are looking (without any wildcards) like in your example, you could use 'in' operator.

```
q) "hello" in ("hello";"goodbye") 
q) 1b
```

If you want more complex regex patterns, then you could use external libraries. KDB supports interfacing with external libraries. For ex you could use [pcre](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/ffi/#pcre-library) library.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Rahul! (Not sure why I didnt use in in the first place!)